# "Could not find any version" when switching from maven-central to jcenter

Tags: android, maven-central, jcenter

I am trying to switch from mavenCentral to jcenter ( as this is the new default for android ) and stumble uppon this problem:

> Could not find any version that matches com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.+.

interetingly it should be there:

http://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlecode/android-query/android-query/0.25.9/

it works when I do not use + for the minor part:

```
compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
```